# Angular 2 abstract directive needs decorator

Tags: angular

I want to implement an  Angular 2 Directive hierachy.  A base, abstract class sets up handlers for mouse events and hands off processing the cursor position to a concrete derived class that does specific processing upon the model.  I have an abstract class

```js
    export abstract class DragDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
        constructor(protected elementRef: ElementRef) { }
        @Input() dragTarget: Draggable;
        ngAfterViewInit() {
            // various rxjs Observables and subscription handlers for mouseevents, including ...
            ...  this.handlePoint(point);
            ...
        }
        abstract handlePoint(point: Point): void;
    }
```

And a concrete directive:

```js
    @Directive({
        selector: '[drag-anywhere]'
    })
    export class DragAnywhereDirective extends DragDirective {
        handlePoint(point: Point): void {
            this.dragTarget.setPosition(point);
        }
    }
```

At runtime I get the error:
**Can't resolve all parameters for DragAnywhereDirective: (?).**
unless I also decorate the abstract class with:

```js
    @Directive({
        selector: '[unusable-because-its-not-concrete]'
    })
```

Why is it necessary to decorate the abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the elementRef to the constructor in your base class like so

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[drag-anywhere]'
})
export class DragAnywhereDirective extends DragDirective {
   constructor(protected elementRef: ElementRef) {
       super(elementRef);
   }

   handlePoint(point: any): void {
       this.dragTarget.setPosition(point);
   }
}
```

For more details on decorators check out this [blog post](https://toddmotto.com/angular-decorators#how-decorators-are-applied) by Todd Motto

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks.  So, in Typescript, the base class's public constructor is not available by default in a derived class?  Do you have to declare one and call super()?

Comment: not necessarily, only if you are injecting services or initializing stuff in your constructor